# Error al usar una clave pública

Tags: python, python-3.x

tengo un pequeño problema con la librería Cipher de python3.

Tengo que realizar el cifrado de un archivo con AES y para ello tengo que generar una clave simétrica que tendrá que ser usada posteriormente por el receptor. Para ello, cifro de igual forma la clave simétrica con la clave pública del receptor pero a la hora de cifrarla me da el siguiente error:

```html
raise ValueError("RSA key format is not supported")
ValueError: RSA key format is not supported
```

El código para el cifrado de la clave simétrica es el siguiente:

```html
def cifrarClaveSimetrica(self, recKey):

        key = RSA.importKey(str.encode(recKey))
        cipher = PKCS1_v1_5.new(key)
        return cipher.encrypt(self.asyKey)
```

El argumento "recKey" es la clave pública del receptor y es de tipo str.

Aquí un ejemplo de como sería su contenido:

```html
b'-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAtOBYkrIopDwb0AOvhxrU\nuY8IrwqXnuzw4c/DhD1nqlMLPEATNjXJRddt/1yuFKLACyGTMg3qcjh9vb1Sn2Xo\nTUUVZsO7M3En7Oe4mFGTME+3HuDPzOxgsbuK7sMTBPMU/Hk+7WZCg01Io5KanTxI\nNuEHALt7e+8n7goRJJwuhmatzkVVBsk9fdF0J+DfOTPNeE//VkJIuEuAI1wxKYbv\nmXc4PR5jWwSNfG4w6cWbHyxkdQVe38mF2YwCxLGVsKTft3HcmnwFooA/rwpB6v8d\nkzNJNjQlkSMmIrxA3AhCUKEjpYzgmh88d609jpzaHYSAgemJF86zeAd/im1PzImc\nMwIDAQAB\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----'
```

¿Alguna idea de qué puede estar pasando?

Gracias y un saludo.

Comment: No estoy muy seguro, pero creo que la armadura `----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY----` y `----END PUBLIC KEY----` no forma parte de lo que es la clave pública en sí. Prueba a quitarlo.

Comment: @abulafia No, el error sigue siendo el mismo

Comment: Esta [pregunta de stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10569189/how-to-read-a-rsa-public-key-in-pem-pkcs1-format) tiene pinta de ser el mismo problema. Mira si te vale su solución

Comment: @abulafia Siguiendo el ejemplo que me has pasado me da un error de padding en la función: b64decode()

Comment: Tienes que quedarte con lo que es la clave, sin la armadura y sin retornos de carro.  Mira la respuesta que acabo de escribir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La clave que lees del fichero y que tienes en `recKey`, no está en el formato correcto (que debería ser binario). Lo que tienes es una codificación en base64 y delimitada por una armadura específica. Esto es lo que tienes:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAtOBYkrIopDwb0AOvhxrU
uY8IrwqXnuzw4c/DhD1nqlMLPEATNjXJRddt/1yuFKLACyGTMg3qcjh9vb1Sn2Xo
TUUVZsO7M3En7Oe4mFGTME+3HuDPzOxgsbuK7sMTBPMU/Hk+7WZCg01Io5KanTxI
NuEHALt7e+8n7goRJJwuhmatzkVVBsk9fdF0J+DfOTPNeE//VkJIuEuAI1wxKYbv
mXc4PR5jWwSNfG4w6cWbHyxkdQVe38mF2YwCxLGVsKTft3HcmnwFooA/rwpB6v8d
kzNJNjQlkSMmIrxA3AhCUKEjpYzgmh88d609jpzaHYSAgemJF86zeAd/im1PzImc
MwIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

En realidad, contiene varias líneas. Lo que nos interesa es lo que está en el medio, entre la primera y la última (que son la armadura). El siguiente código parte esa cadena por líneas, quita la primera y la última, y ensambla de nuevo las líneas de enmedio en una sola cadena, eliminando los retornos de carro que había entre ellas:

```
clave = b"".join(recKey.split(b'\n')[1:-1])
```

El resultado (valor de `clave`) es:

```
b'MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAtOBYkrIopDwb0AOvhxrUuY8IrwqXnuzw4c/DhD1nqlMLPEATNjXJRddt/1yuFKLACyGTMg3qcjh9vb1Sn2XoTUUVZsO7M3En7Oe4mFGTME+3HuDPzOxgsbuK7sMTBPMU/Hk+7WZCg01Io5KanTxINuEHALt7e+8n7goRJJwuhmatzkVVBsk9fdF0J+DfOTPNeE//VkJIuEuAI1wxKYbvmXc4PR5jWwSNfG4w6cWbHyxkdQVe38mF2YwCxLGVsKTft3HcmnwFooA/rwpB6v8dkzNJNjQlkSMmIrxA3AhCUKEjpYzgmh88d609jpzaHYSAgemJF86zeAd/im1PzImcMwIDAQAB'
```

Ahora ya puedes intentar [la solución](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10574723/1264820) dada en otra pregunta de Stack Overflow a un problema similar. Pasas esa clave a binario (decodificando el base64) e intentas importarla como RSA:

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from base64 import b64decode

keyDER = b64decode(clave)
keyPub = RSA.importKey(keyDER)
```

Comment: Creo que cogía mal la parte del medio. Lo he probado y funciona perfectamente. Muchas gracias!